# Degree formula for multivariable polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Currently I am learning abstract algebra. The text we are using is Dummit Foote's abstract algebra. It says that the degree formula also holds for multivariable polynomial ring when the coefficient $R$ is an integral domain. Intuitively, this sounds correct, however I am having trouble to formulate a formal proof.

The definition of multivariable polynomial:

> The polynomial ring in the varaibles $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ with coefficients in $R$, denoted $R[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$ , is defined inductively by
>   $$R[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]=R[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1}][x_n]$$

The definition of degree is the following:

> A monic term $x^{d_1}x^{d_2}\cdots x^{d_n}$ is called simply a monomial. The exponent $d_i$ is called the degree in $x_i$ of the term and the sum $$d=d_1+d_2+\cdots d_n$$
>   is called the degree of the term.

The degree formula in the text is

> degree $p(x)q(x)$ = degree $p(x)$+degree $q(x)$ if $p(x),q(x)$ are non zero. (Provided $R$ is an integral domain)

It is straight forward to see the multivariable polynomial ring is an integral domain provided $R$ is an integral domain. However, there might be cancellation happens so I don't see how can I prove the degree formula. Can someone give a formal argument on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $p(x)=1+2x^2y$ and $q(x)=2xy$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4[x, y]$. Does the formula work?

Comment: A better notation in the previous comment should be $p(x, y), q(x, y)$

Comment: @freshman Thanks for comment. But $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain right?

Comment: Right. But you have written "polynomial ring with coefficients in $R$".  I understood that you were considering $R$ as a ring in the general meaning of an associative ring. Would be better to write "How to prove the degree formula in $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $R$ is an integral domain?"

Comment: hh great point, I will edit it.