# when finding the highest degree in a polynomial why do we add the exponents of each variable in a term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, in the expression:
$$x^3y^2+4x^2$$Why is the highest degree 5 and not 3? why do we have to add the exponents together when they are different variables to find the highest degree?

Comment: That depends entirely on what question you are wanting to ask and what meaning of the word "degree" is in this context.  Some times you want to talk about the highest combined degree.  Some times you want to talk about highest degree of $x$ only.  Some times you want to talk about something else entirely.  It all depends on context and context is entirely up to you and/or your teacher.

Comment: the context is just to find the degree of the expression. So I interpret that just means what is the highest degree of the expression

Comment: It's really nothing but just definition. The degree of a polynomial is by definition the highest degree of it's monomials. And the degree of monomial is by definition the sum of degrees of all variables that exist in this monomial.

Comment: It is common practice to consider the sum of degrees here since that way it works like we are used to for single variable scenarios... namely that you have $\deg(f\cdot g)\leq \deg(f)\cdot \deg(g)$.  See [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Classification).

Comment: Just to emphasize... when you are in a scenario like this where there are multiple possible interpretations and multiple possible answers... that does not necessarily mean that certain answers and interpretations are incorrect or not useful.  Those are just the right answers to different questions than one another.

Comment: oh, ok thanks I guess I just didn't understand that by definition that's how it is. I thought there was a mathematical reason/explanation behind it

Comment: My guess is that it originally arose from how area and volume units combine. The product of length and width of a rectangle, $LW,$ is an area, the volume of a cylinder is $\pi r^2h,$ the volume of a rectangular solid is $LWH,$ etc. Besides the geometric names which are still used -- square for 2nd power and cube for 3rd power -- higher powers used to have geometric names such as "square-square", "square-cube", "cube-cube", etc. See the various answers and comments to the mathoverflow question [History of powers beyond squares and cubes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/181244/15780).

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555616/degree-formula-for-multivariable-polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where there are more than
one related but different variants of a concept.
First, for monomials, there is the concept of
the **highest** degree of the variables. This can
apply to a fixed variable or all of the variables.
The other variation is the **total** degree of all
of the variables.
These variations make sense and are useful in some
contexts and not in others.

For a a polynomial,
define its degree to be the maximum of the degrees
of its monomials. Thus, there is the total degree
of a polynomial and the highest degree over all of
the variables or the highest degree over a fixed
variable.

For example, your polynomial $\,x^3y^2+4x^2\,$ has
total degree is $5.$ The highest degree over all of
the variables is $3$ which is also the highest degree
over $x$ while the highest degree over $y$ is $2.$